# libXtst installed with yum; where is /usr/lib/libXtst.so.6?

Tags: linux, installation, yum, file-not-found

libXtst is installed using '`yum install libXtst`' successfully.

```
[root@prdsup1 Packages]# yum reinstall libXtst
Loaded plugins: security, ulninfo
Setting up Reinstall Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libXtst.x86_64 0:1.2.2-2.1.el6 will be reinstalled
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved
=============================================================================================================================
 Package                   Arch                     Version                         Repository                          Size
=============================================================================================================================
Reinstalling:
 libXtst                   x86_64                   1.2.2-2.1.el6                   ol6_latest_local                    18 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================
Reinstall     1 Package(s)

Total download size: 18 k
Installed size: 27 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
libXtst-1.2.2-2.1.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                      |  18 kB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : libXtst-1.2.2-2.1.el6.x86_64                                                                              1/1 
  Verifying  : libXtst-1.2.2-2.1.el6.x86_64                                                                              1/1 

Installed:
  libXtst.x86_64 0:1.2.2-2.1.el6   

Complete!
```

But I can not find `/usr/lib/libXtst.so.6` file with below commands:

```
[root@prdsup1 Packages]# rpm -qa | grep Xtst
libXtst-devel-1.2.2-2.1.el6.x86_64
libXtst-1.2.2-2.1.el6.x86_64
[root@prdsup1 Packages]# ls -al /usr/lib/*tst*
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/*tst*: No such file or directory
[root@prdsup1 Packages]# ls -al /usr/lib/*Xt*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 Sep 24  2015 /usr/lib/libXt.so.6 -> libXt.so.6.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 376964 Aug 18  2014 /usr/lib/libXt.so.6.0.0
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Answer (score 1):

It is in /usr/lib64.
The following command gives you the answer.

```
rpm -ql libXtst-devel-1.2.2-2.1.el6.x86_64
```